# Find and count gear opencv

Tags: opencv

I need some help with opencv and gearwheel detection.

My task: count gearwheel teeth from images like this: 
[image: source]

Im trying to use HoughCircles method but got bad results lile this: 
[image: hough]

Otsu threshold:

[image: otsu]

Code (on openCV Java wrapper):

```
       Mat des = new Mat(sourceImg.rows(), sourceImg.cols(), sourceImg.type());

   Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceImg, sourceImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 4);

   Imgproc.GaussianBlur(sourceImg,des, new Size(3,3),0,0);     
   Imgproc.threshold(des, des, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

   Imgproc.Canny(des, des, 0 , 1);
   displayImage(Mat2BufferedImage(des));
   Mat circles = new Mat();

   Imgproc.HoughCircles(des, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0, 50, 70.0, 30.0, 100, 0);

   /// Draw the circles detected
   for(int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++ )
   {
       double vCircle[] = circles.get(0,i);

        if (vCircle == null)
            break;

        Point pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
        int radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);

        // draw the found circle
        Core.circle(des, pt, radius, new Scalar(255,255,255), 3);
        Core.circle(des, pt, 3, new Scalar(255,0,0), 3);
    }
```

What is right way for my task? How to count teeth? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I tried. The code is in C++ but you can easily adapt it to Java.

- load the image and resize it to half the size
- erode the image, use Canny to detect edges, then dilate to connect the edges
- find contours and choose the largest contour
- find the convexhull of this largest contour. Number of point in the convexhull will give you a rough value for the number of teeth

Here's the largest contour and the convexhull points:

[image]

I get a value of 77 with the following code.

```
    Mat gray = imread("16atchc.jpg", 0);
    Mat small, bw, er, kernel;
    resize(gray, small, Size(), .5, .5);
    kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    erode(small, er, kernel);
    Canny(er, bw, 50, 150);
    dilate(bw, bw, kernel);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    int imax = 0, areamax = 0;
    findContours(bw, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
    {
        Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        int area = rect.width * rect.height;
        if (area > areamax)
        {
            areamax = area;
            imax = idx;
        }
    }
    vector<Point> hull;
    convexHull(contours[imax], hull);

    cout << contours[imax].size() << ", " << hull.size() << endl;
```